# How to properly export a class as a module in Node.js

Tags: node.js, module

I have **class A** and **class B**, and **class A** extends **class B**.

But they are in different files. Now in my 'server.js' I want to use **class A**.

My code in `a.js` is written as this:

```
const B = require('./b.js');

module.exports = class A extends B {}
```

But it gave me an error on line 2 at symbol `B` saying:

*TypeError: Class extends value #`<Object>` is not a function or null*

How to properly export a class which extends another class in Node.js?

Comment: Could you share your actual code? The code you listed above should work fine, when I use it like [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ba9822de5344acf5803b1d3cecb4d486) I get no issues from running `a.js`.

Comment: just write `export class A extends B {}`

Comment: ^ That won't work unless you're using something like Babel since modules haven't been implemented yet. If you're not using a transpiler, you have to use `require`, `module.exports`, and `exports`.

Comment: @saadq Thanks I forget to make `B` `module.exports`. Now it works.